# Understanding of how the trigger connector works on a boom-arm vehicle barrier

Tags: relay, trigger

I would like to know how the trigger (TRG) pin works on the boom-arm vehicle barrier. From my understanding looking at the circuit below for an external radio receiver, when the trg pin is grounded is activates the [boom barrier](https://www.turnstar.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Turnstar-VELOCITY-Automatic-Vehicle-Barrier-4.pdf).

However what is happing at the trg pin?

Is there a micro-controller pin that is connected to the trg pin. This micro-controller pin then detects is the trg pin is high or low. The micro-controller pin detects a high when the remote is not pressed. When the remote is pressed the trg pin is then grounded. This change in state (HIGH-LOW) then activates the boom barrier.

Is this a correct interpretation?

[image]

[Second question](https://www.turnstar.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Turnstar-VELOCITY-Automatic-Vehicle-Barrier-4.pdf)

From this manual, they say the boom barrier is "Triggered through a normally open dry contact". Does this mean that I must supply the control signal that closes the circuit? Or does it mean I must supply the actually voltage that runs the boom barrier?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain what a "boom barrier" is?

Comment: @Transistor it is shown in the "Second question". I did not want to add another picture because the post is already quite long with the current picture.

Comment: That sounds like your interpretation is correct - when the pin is grounded, the controller activates the boom barrier. The voltage to run it must be supplied somewhere, but not on the trg pin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the remote is pressed the trg pin is then grounded.

This would be a standard implementation. A weak pull-up resistor pulls the input normally high. A ground connection will pull it down and overcome the pull-up.

> From this manual, they say the boom barrier is "Triggered through a normally open dry contact".

"Dry" here means that the contact is isolated from whatever is controlling the contact and no voltage appears on it from the driving circuitry. It is a standard interfacing technique to allow systems working on differing voltages to interact with each other without damage or complexity.

If you are adding another trigger then the simplest thing is to use a relay contact or a pushbutton to switch the controller.

Comment: Thank you. For the second answer provided. How do you know whether or not you must provide the control signal or the power to the device (the control circuit is already implemented and you must provide the power to the load)? I always get confused about this. I know a relay is used to separate two circuits. Where the control circuits are used to break or connect the second circuit power. But how do you know if you must provide the control signal or the power to the second ciruit?

Comment: What is your second circuit?

Comment: Sorry about that so basically for these boom vehicle barriers, driveway gate motors etc, the Trg pin is always your control signal (as long as the data sheet says so). And they are always pulled up to Vcc. So all I have to do to trigger the system is ground the Trg pin? Or connect a arduino to a relay and connect COM of the relay to ground and N/O or N/C to the Trg pin of the boom barrier. Depending on when I want to activate the boom barrier.

Comment: Correct. And the relay provides isolation between your Arduino circuit and your gateway controller so you don't have to worry about possible damage provided you only connect the relay contacts to the gateway controller.