# Is this implementation of activating of boom-arm vehicle barrier correct?

Tags: arduino, relay, trigger

[Previous Post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521938/understanding-of-how-the-trigger-connector-works-on-a-boom-arm-vehicle-barrier/521945?noredirect=1#comment1342094_521945)

From my previous, I asked about how the trig pin works on the boom-arm vehicle barrier. I would like to know if the below circuit is correct?

This circuit assumes the boom barrier opens when the trg pin is grounded. The relay is a 12V DC 10A relay.

The circuit uses an Arduino to trigger the boom barrier via a relay by using a MOSFET. So in theory when the Arduino is HIGH the MOSFET activates and de-energizes the relay. When the Arduino is LOW the MOSFET is opened and therefore will energize the relay thus grounding the trig pin.

The figure suppose to say boom-arm vehicle barrier, not driveway gate, but they use the same setup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX0JEd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Updated schematic
[image]

Comment: No. That's not a clever or efficient way of driving a relay, and it'll waste a lot of power. Read about "low side switch".

Comment: @BrianDrummond could you check if the updated schematic is now correct?

Comment: Better. Note that the relay now operates when the input is HIGH whereas before it operated when the input was LOW (transistor OFF) or maybe never operated at all (thanks to R2). If this is the opposite of what you want, use NC instead of NO on the relay.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Could you explain why the first circuit was not correct and what caused it to be inefficient? Could you also note your comment as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @Joey - think about what the switch aspect of the relay in your first circuit was doing.  Was it powering the relay?  Or was it de-powering the realay by shorting it out?

Comment: In addition to Chris's point, when the relay is ON it is in series with 100R, which will drop part of the supply voltage : the relay may simply not operate on the remaining voltage, or be unreliable.